# Java: Unsupported Content-Coding: text/xml posting text/xml

Tags: java, xml, apache, httprequest

I an posting to a service via Java and receiving an Unsupported Content-Coding: text/xml error.

I know that the service successfully receives and processes my post and attempts to send back the appropriate response. The service, located on another computer, emits a log. I also sent that log to the vendor that wrote the daemon/service, and was told that the service complied with my request and that the problem is on the Java end.

The problems seems to be setting up the txt/xml content type of the response, judging by the error message.

Error Stack Trace:

```
org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:188)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at PkgNetAccelerator32.htsLink.createLink(htsLink.java:100)
...
Caused by: org.apache.http.HttpException: Unsupported Content-Coding: text/xml
    at org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseContentEncoding.process(ResponseContentEncoding.java:98)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:139)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:200)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:85)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
        ... 14 more
```

Source Code:

```
String strPathLocal = "http://192.168.20.65:8080/xml/link";
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(strPathLocal);

String xmlPost = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Whatever>...</Whatever>";
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(xmlPost);
entity.setContentType("text/xml");
httpPost.setEntity(entity);

CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

System.out.println(response2.getStatusLine());
HttpEntity entity2 = response2.getEntity();
EntityUtils.consume(entity2);
response2.close();
```

I took out the try-catch blocks and certain other stuff for readability.

The code never makes it past the httpclient.execute() line.

I did some searching and saw one ticket use "application/xml". I tried that, however that caused the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me like your server is sending a header such as

```
Content-Encoding: text/xml
```

when it (probably) should be sending

```
Content-Type: text/xml
```

As it stands, Apache's `HttpClient` can handle content encodings of type `gzip`, `x-gzip`, `deflate`, and `identity`. For any other value, it throws exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer, but I do not follow what change you would have me make in code, if anything. The service definitely liked what I sent and reported no errors on the CENTOS terminal window. It even gave the proper response. The problem is with the response, has to be. RC in the other answer seems to have said as much. More in comment for RC.

Comment: @sarah That's what I'm saying. The server is sending a header in its response which your http client doesn't know how to handle. It feels to me like your server is sending content-encoding when it should be sending content-type header.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you said better now. Thank you for the clarification. I just looked up an article, question ID 5938007, here on StackOverflow, as the difference between content encoding and content type. I am actively contacting the vendor (not my service) to find out about their response.

Comment: I heard back from the vendor. They wrote me back: [You are correct, I overlooked this...the response header is "Content-Coding text/xml", but it should be "Content-Type text/xml". This is the problem, just fixed it.] They sent me a new drop, which fixed the problem, although introduced another couple of problems. Thanks!

Comment: @sarah That's the beauty of the software lifecycle. :)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [`ResponseContentEncoding` sources](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/xref/org/apache/http/client/protocol/ResponseContentEncoding.html#98) this exception occurs when the **server** answer contains a non handled content encoding header.

So you need to adapt the server code to "serve" its answer with a proper content encoding.

Comment: Thank you for the answer RC. I agree that on the face of it the problem is, as you said, more than likely that HttpClients.createDefault() is not happy with the response that it got. I have no clue what the response that it sends back is. I have to contact the vendor and see if I can get more information on that.  Stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem consuming an API, giving out '**Unsupported Content-Coding: application/xml**' in the stack trace.

Don't think '**Content-Coding**' is a thing at all according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers. But will entertain on the fact that the server is misconfigured to give out that information which should either be '**Content-Encoding**' or '**Content-Type**'.